# How to create a duplicate changelist in Perforce during integration across branches?

Tags: perforce

Is there a way to duplicate the change list description using p4 command line when integrating from the source change list across branches ?

Details:

For e.g. 
**p4 integ -t -b branch_a_to_branch_b -s //my/tree/...@2425,@2425**

integrates files from changelist 2425 to the **default** changelist in the target branch branch_b from source branch branch_a

Is it possible to create a new changelist which has the same description as the source changelist ?

Then the target integration can be done on this new changelist.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to do this in one command, but it seems like it would be easy enough to script up.  You might want to look at the commands p4v runs when it integrates, as it has the option to integrate to a new changelist.  Then it would simply be a matter of changing the description of the new changelist to match the old one.